# Automate conversion txt to xls

Tags: python, excel, text

I am looking for the cheapest way of automating the conversion of all the text files (tab-delimited) in a folder structure into .xls format, keeping the shape of columns and rows as it is.

**Edit:** this did the trick:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
f = open('Text.txt', 'r+')
row_list = []
for row in f:
    row_list.append(row.split())
column_list = zip(*row_list)
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
i = 0 
for column in column_list:
    for item in range(len(column)):
        worksheet.write(item, i, column[item])
    workbook.save('Excel.xls')
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just rename all of the files from *.txt to *.xls. Excel will automatically partition the data, keeping the original shape.

I'm not going to write your code for you, but here is a head start:

- You can list a directories contents using [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)
- You can use [`os.path.isdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) and [`os.path.isfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to see if each 'thing' you just found in your intial directory is a file or a directory, and act on accordingly
- You can use [`os.rename()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename a file and [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) to delete a file
- You can use [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split the files name and extension, or just `file.endswith('.txt')` to work on only the correct files

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to then read the files via xlrd which without opening the file in Excel and saving it will not recognize the file as Excel file by just renaming it.

Comment: @lhcgeneva you've confused me... you mention trying to avoid use of `xlrd` but are going to use it anyway... so why not use `xlwt` to convert the text files?

Comment: @Jon Clements I thought it was going to be bulky using xlwt, which is why I wanted to avoid it to convert the files. Is there an easy way to do it with xlwt?

Comment: @lhcgeneva use the `csv` module to get your rows from the text files and then use example code from the `xlwt` docs to create your xls... (and use Gareth's suggestion above for walking your files)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import xlwt
textfile = "C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/test.txt"

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False        


style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '#,###0.00'  

#for textfile in textfiles:
f = open(textfile, 'r+')
row_list = []
for row in f:
    row_list.append(row.split('|'))
column_list = zip(*row_list)
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
i = 0
for column in column_list:
    for item in range(len(column)):
        value = column[item].strip()
        if is_number(value):
            worksheet.write(item, i, float(value), style=style)
        else:
            worksheet.write(item, i, value)
    i+=1
workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

Sorry, must have pasted in the wrong thing...