# Convert text files to excel files using python

Tags: xls

I am working on INFORMIX 4GL programs. That programs produce output text files.This is an example of the output:

```
Lot No|Purchaser name|Billing|Payment|Deposit|Balance|                
J1006|JAUHARI BIN HAMIDI|5285.05|4923.25|0.00|361.80|                 
J1007|LEE, CHIA-JUI AKA LEE, ANDREW J. R.|5366.15|5313.70|0.00|52.45| 
J1008|NAZRIN ANEEZA BINTI NAZARUDDIN|5669.55|5365.30|0.00|304.25|     
J1009|YAZID LUTFI BIN AHMAD LUTFI|3180.05|3022.30|0.00|157.75|
```

This text files can manually convert to excel files.But, I wanna ask, is there any script that I can use to convert .txt files to .xls files ?

Hi all,now I'm already can convert text files to excell file by python using script that was given from user named Rami Helmy.A big thanks for him.But now,That script will produce more than one excell files depends on the number of '|' from the text files.Beside that,That script also can only convert one text files.I a going to convert all text files without state the name of text files.Therefore,I am looking such a way on how to this script going to:

- output only one excell file
- convert all .txt files from the directory that was given from user.
- output excell's file name are automaticly copied from the file name of text files.

I am new in python,hopefully someone can help me to solve my problems.Thank You..

done all the task,but there was some problem..the column that had green mark is format as textfile,so I can't make any calculation on that column.That column need to convert to number format.other from that,  output excell files contains an "square" symbol like this:

[image]

then, how to make the green mark column format as number when convert file? and how can I ensure that there is no square symbol like that? Please help,thank you...

That strange square symbol are already gone but that green mark are still exist.
[image]

Hi all. I had one question to ask, I already got script that was given by RamiHelmi, but the extension file name will produce file such as:

tester.txt --> tester.txt.xls

therefore,how can i remove the '.txt. on the output files so that it will only produce "tester.xls" files extension.Hopefully,someone can help solve my problem..thank you

Comment: There are some libraries that you could use to create excel files phpExcel, jExcel, i think every language has is own librarie (or several).

Comment: One idea is to change all `|` for semicolons `;` and rename to .csv files so excel will be able to open it as spreadsheet.

Comment: thanks for response ,but I'm still don't know how to solve it..

Comment: Updated the script to fix the bug that you mentioned

Comment: wow ! its works..thanks a lot, may god bless you Rami Helmy !

Comment: Rami Helmy, I had one more question to be asked.. see updated question..

Comment: I've updated the Script in my answer

Comment: i'm sorry Rami Helmy,still need your help, I test the output and there got some problems, I have updated my question :(

Comment: @RamiHelmy please help :(

Comment: @Please post the input text files having the problem

Comment: I had shown above in image input and output of the files, there was an strange character at the end of data.and the green mark box are format as text,not the number,so I cannot make an calculation.I had google on internet, they show manual step to change text to number format, I need an script to solve this problem,please help :(

Comment: @RamiHelmy you need other information about this problem?

Comment: @RahimJaafar, I've updated the script to strip the string before writing it to the XLS file. Try it again

Comment: thanks a lot @RamiHelmy , one problem had settled, that strange square symbol are dissapear, but that that green mark are still saved as text files.. I have update my question, please help..

Comment: @RamiHelmy are you there?

Comment: @RahimJaafar just updated the script :)

Comment: hi @RamiHelmy can I ask some question?

Comment: @RamiHelmy are you there ?

Comment: but,i can't play skype right now.. i'm at office,huhu.. can i have your email?

Comment: @RamiHelmy , as what i stated above, there's a problem i need to solve, the extension should be (.xls) only, not (.txt.xls)  ,please help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To automate that, you can use that python script described here:

[Automate conversion txt to xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274021/automate-conversion-txt-to-xls)

Here is an updated version of the python script that will convert all the text files having the format that you described in a given directory to XLS files and save them in the same directory:

```
# mypath should be the complete path for the directory containing the input text files
mypath = raw_input("Please enter the directory path for the input files: ")

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and '.txt' in  f]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False        

import xlwt
import xlrd

style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '#,###0.00'  

for textfile in textfiles:
    f = open(textfile, 'r+')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        row_list.append(row.split('|'))
    column_list = zip(*row_list)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    i = 0
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            value = column[item].strip()
            if is_number(value):
                worksheet.write(item, i, float(value), style=style)
            else:
                worksheet.write(item, i, value)
        i+=1
    workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

**EDIT**

The script above will get a list of all the text files in the given directory specified in `mypath` variable and then convert each text file to an XLS file named `generated_xls0.xls` then the next file will be named `generated_xls1.xls` etc...

**EDIT**

strip the string before writing it to the XLS file

**EDIT**

modified the script to handle the formatting of numbers

Comment: ok,thanks.. i already know how to convert manually like this.But, I finding a script that can be used for converting it, or is there any software that can be convert automatically...?

Comment: i'm sorry, wanna ask.. actually where should I paste codes above? I'm never learn script before.Please help ,thank you

Comment: That's a python script so you need to have Python installed.
Depending on your OS, download the appropriate distribution from here:
http://www.python.org/getit/
Or try portable Python if you don't want to install it. http://portablepython.com/

Comment: ok thanks already installed portable python.Then , which programs which script that you give above should be pasted?

Comment: That means the the module is not available. Try that python distribution. It has all the libraries pre-intalled including the xlrt.
https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Comment: ok, waiting for download that python distribution.by the way, I wanted to ask, that scrip I just need to paste once time only right? for example after convert that files to excel.Then, There were another text files same format like I shown in question that need to be convert to excel,then how can its convert for the second time?

Comment: thanks a lot Rami Helmi,Now i'm still in process of installing the python.There was an problem while installing,but its ok, i will try solve it and use script that you had give.Thnk you

Comment: sorry Rami Helmi,i'm still need to ask.The script just can be paste line by line to the console?Is that the correct way to paste it?

Comment: Copy the script, then type "%paste" on the IPython console to paste the script while preserving the formatting

Comment: sure shoot your question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this could be like this:

```
#coding:utf-8
import pandas as pd
import sys
input = sys.argv[1]
pd.read_csv(input, encoding='utf8', sep='\|', dtype='unicode').to_excel('output/' + input + '.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: This looks very simple, but can you actually use read_csv with a pike delimiter.  When I tried I received the following error: 'c' engine does not support regex separators.  Which I image has to do with the fact that I am trying to read a .txt not a .csv.  Just wondering if there is a work around in pandas.  Thanks.

Comment: I have got the same error: 'c' engine does not upport regex separators. And I wonder if if relates with that the txt file I'm dealing with is seperated by tab not by '|' ?